# Do Octadic Capacitors Use More Energy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Do capacitors from Ender IO use more energy for operations? I found two conflicting sources. [This site](https://ftb.gamepedia.com/Octadic_Capacitor) claims they use up to 4 times more energy, while on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/SleepyTrousers/EnderIO/wiki/Capacitor) of the mod it says nothing about that.

Comment: I believe it uses more per tick but not operation, but I'd have to do a test to find out for sure

Comment: Yes, they do. I have been using them for years. It seems that the GitHub page may be missing some information

Comment: @David Can you please write that as an answer?

Comment: @Fabian done. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The short answer:

Yes, increasing the tier of Capacitors used (None -> Double -> Octadic) will use more power.

### The long answer:

A machine at the base tier can use (X) amount of power at maximum and can store (Y) at maximum. For this example, I will be using the [SAG Mill](https://ftbwiki.org/SAG_Mill).

### Example:

At base, the SAG Mill can store 100,000 Redstone Flux (RF) and can use a maximum of 20 RF per tick (20 ticks every second)

[image]

With the addition of a [Double Layer Capacitor](https://ftbwiki.org/Double-Layer_Capacitor), the SAG Mill can now store 300,000 RF and use 60 per tick

[image]

Finally, with the addition of an [Octadic Capacitor](https://ftbwiki.org/Octadic_Capacitor), the machine can store a whopping 500,000 RF and can use 100 per tick

[image]

### Conclusion:

Octadic capacitors ***will*** consume more power.

The question stated that on a wiki page, the Octadic Capacitor was said to use up to 4x as much power, which may be true on some machines, but will vary from machine to machine.